# Scheduler Booking Flow - Heading Customization for Select Service Resource and Service Appointment Time Screen

Tags: visual-workflow, customization, lightning-scheduler

I am trying to edit or hide the mention "Who do you want to meet?" on top of the Select Service Resource and Service Appointment Time Screen Flow component. This is not mapped as something we can edit in the documentation (Saleforce Scheduler -> Customize the Select Service Resource and Service Appointment Time Screen).

Is there any way to edit this at all ?

[image: Map of editable elements as per the documentation]

Comment: I have the same issue, need to update "Who do you want to meet". Were you able to find a solution? Thank you so much!

Comment: Unfortunately no, we ended up leaving it there. It makes no sense because we only have one resource available but found no way around it..